# Nodejs error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use the Exchange API (send mails, and create events) from a nodejs program.

I started by trying the `node-ews` npm package, but when I attempted to make a request, I got an exception:

```
"unable to get local issuer certificate" "UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCAL".
```

I tried to figure it out for a while, but when failed I thought I'd try a different approach - sending a soap request.

I installed the npm package `easysoap` but when I tried to make a request I got the same error.

It seems like I'm going through too much troubles in order to make it work.
It would be a simple task to perform, using a .Net library in C#.
What am I missing?

Is there a better method of doing that?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:

I have tried to use fiddler to try and see the response from the exchange server, but I don't even see a request.

Comment: Are you using a proxy, or antivirus software that intercepts TLS connections?

Comment: No. Also, A friend of mine used a C# library to interact with the same exchange server and it worked.

Comment: Not a great solution, but perhaps it works when you set the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` environment variable.

Comment: I've tried that too. Same error..

Comment: if you are open to use another library for this purpose, take a look at [ews-javascript-api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api). you can easily port c# code to Node.
[disclaimer - I am the author of library]